# Appengine model filtering problem

Tags: python, google-app-engine, model, filter

I've got an entity class:

```
class User(db.Model):
    local = db.TextProperty(required=True)
    jid = db.TextProperty(required=True)
```

Later in code I'm checking if a user exists:

```
def parseMessageFromJid(self, message, mesFrom) :
        #user = User.all().filter(' jid', mesFrom.lower().strip()).get()
        user = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM User " +
                "WHERE jid = :1",
                mesFrom.lower().strip()).get()
    if user is None :
      if message.body.strip().lower().find("register") != 0 :
        message.reply(HELP_MSG)
      elif message.body.strip().lower().find("register") == 0 :
        uname = message.body.strip().replace("register ", "", 1).replace(" ", "") + "@mybot.com"
        user = User(jid=mesFrom,local=uname)
        user.put()
        message.reply("Ok. You are now registered.")
    else :
      # User registered, proceed
      self.send_to_bots(message, user.local)
```

I tried both approaches: gql and the commented code. Both approaches return `None`, althought the user is there: I can see it in my console and it is there when I do `User.all()`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TextProperty` is not indexed.
Use `StringProperty`